# 'Choose an option' in IE broke Magento 1.7

Tags: jquery, magento

After upgrading from Magento to 1.5 to 1.7, my 'choose an option' is not working anymore.
I have this problem only in IE. I have searched for solutions online, but couldn't find anything related to this specific problem.

Please help me, already trying to upgrade to 1.7 for such a long time and I keep finding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable and css compression and for javascript.

there is error in javascript.

Comment: Decompressing the javascript files in: system -> developer-> javascript settings -> No

This works, but doesnt sound like a safe solution though, is it?

Comment: Ill keep this solution for now, until I will upgrade till 1.8. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please enable javascript debugger in IE.

to enable javascript error notification.

Go TO :

Open IE 
Tools -> Internet Options -> Advance Tab.

Check Display Notification about every script error.

and than refresh page.

So you will able to debug script error.